# About linking files using Mac terminal

Tags: c, macos, terminal

Okay here goes, I'm completely new at this, started learning the terminal just about 2 days ago. I'm slowly but surely getting the hang of it, now I'm stuck on this and I've been trying to fix it for a good hour. It's a rather simple question as I am a newby.

I have a C file in my desktop and a Header file in a folder in my desktop. I'm including that header in my C file. I have to link them (currently doing a tutorial, it tells me to link, but doesn't show me how).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options. First, you will need to install the software development environment - it's called Xcode. I think you can get it for free on the AppStore, if not Google it.

Then you need to decide if you want to develop and compile graphically in the Xcode Integrated Development Environment. If you do, start Xcode and create a new project and open your C file and change the "include path" to match the location of your header file. Then click "Build" and "Run"

If you want to do things at the commandline, you'll need to install "Xcode Command Line Tools" - Google it. That will give you a compiler. Then you can compile. I'm not certain which compiler you will get - it could be "llvm" or "gcc" or something else, but the command you are looking for will be something like:

```
gcc -o prog -I /path/to/HeaderFileFolder yoursourcecode.c
```

which will give you a program called "prog" that you can run by typing

```
./prog
```

Comment: You can install just the commandline tools to get gcc - no need for Xcode. Xcode is seriously hard to grok, I've never got it to compile more than a few files successfully let alone autoconf. Just use those commands and you won't get confused (hopefully).

Comment: Still fatal error: header file not found, but I will continue trying.

Comment: If your header is on the desktop, are you using "~" to refer to it? Not all tools recognize this to expand to "the user's root folder". If you do, try with the full path to your header.

Comment: If you are still having problems, please show us where your files are, what command you are using and what errors it gives - because at the moment, we are just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely confusing two different concepts.  The "link" mentioned in the tutorial is probably talking about turning the compiled objects into a single executable.  See http://www.cprogramming.com/compilingandlinking.html for an explanation of what linking means in this context.

What you've provided examples of doing is file system linking, which is totally unrelated.

Providing more details on the tutorial could help refine this answer.

Comment: Sorry, that's pretty much all the tutorial says, it told me to run the sample code using those two files and to link them so that I don't get a "myHeader.h" not found in my C file. Thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: Please do **not** link to cplusplus.com, it's terrible. Something like [this](http://codingfreak.blogspot.com/2008/02/compilation-process-in-gcc.html) would come handy instead.

Comment: @H2CO3, to whom was that comment directed?  Neither Ceelos nor I linked to cplusplus.com.

Comment: By the way, my answer seems out of place now since @Ceelos updated the question to remove the reference to the `ln` command.

Comment: @DaveLouw I don't think that was directed to you; I don't remember. Maybe I was referring to a comment that has been deleted since then.